# How to sum the value of all columns in one row except the ID

Tags: php, mysql, sum, row

I need to sum the totals of a row except the first column.
Something similar too:

SELECT SUM( col2 + col3 + col4 +colN) 
FROM numbers
WHERE user_name =  'person';

My table will continuously have columns added to it. So I want it to automatically pick up the sum of the new columns too without it needing to be hard coded into the query?

```
user_name  | Col | col2 | Col3 | Col4 + other columns.

person1    |  2  |  3   | 76   | 56  etc.    ---------> sum of row

person2    |  6  |  72  | 200  | 13  etc.    ---------> sum of row
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you need to do this, then you'd be well advised to normalize your database in a moe appropriate fashion

Comment: It would help to know a bit more about what kind of information you're storing in Col1, Col2 ... ColN. If you're able to update your question or add a comment here with more details then I'll see if I can update my answer with more of an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not wishing to 'avoid' the question, but it looks like you could do with having a different data structure.

You should consider having a 'users' table with columns for `id` and `user_name`, and a new table (e.g. `properties`) with a row for each of the other columns in your current table (`Col1`, `Col2` ... `ColN`). The new table would then have a column for user_name to link it to  the users table.

That way you'd be able to do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(property_column) FROM properties WHERE user_name = <RequiredUserName>
```

I'd also recommend selecting users by ID (i.e. have the `properties` table with a user_id column, rather than a user_name column), unless you're confident that a user_name is never going to change (and even then...).

Comment: ok, thanks I have done this.  Now I'm trying to insert data into a specific field.   INSERT INTO tablename  (colNumberX)
                  VALUES 500
                  WHERE (ID Coulmn) = *idnumber* ----->something like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to recommend without knowing more context. If your new properties table has columns for user_name, property_name and value, then you could use INSERT INTO properties (user_name, property_name, value) VALUES ("billy", "high score", 500). You may also want to make user_name and property_name both primary keys so that you could add "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" to the end of the query. This would replace values if they already exist for that user / property combination. Might be worth updating your original question with more info or else logging this part as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest solution is to do it in PHP:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from numbers where user = ...");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $row['Id'] = 0; // don't want to sum the Id
    $sum = array_sum($row); // this is the required sum
    ....
}
```

Comment: Did you mean $row['user_name'] = 0; // don't want to sum the user_name ? I know Id would be better. Just working with the OP's existing column names...

Answer (score 0):

As stated you would be better advised revisiting your database structure, 
If you can't and 
If you want to do it in PHP you can get the resultset back and then loop through the fields and exclude the fields you don't want then add up everything else, assuming it is of the right type,  use mysql_field_type to find those of a specific type.